# Modify Chrome Omnibar autofill options

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to change autofill options for the Omnibar (top search bar) in Chrome?  Even just to remove autofill entries?

Starting a couple weeks ago, I am recently running into an issue where it keeps erroneously suggesting random past one-time internet searches of mine instead of frequently visited website URLs.  For instance, currently when I type "g" into the bar, instead of autofilling "gmail.com" (one of my most visited sites) like it always used to it will instead put in whatever my last internet search starting with "g" was.

This is really annoying as I (and I am sure many others) typically go to common sites by just pressing the first letter and hitting enter.  Is there any way to fix this?